# ¿ como controlar que no se dupliquen los productos al insertar en una tabla con campos input generados

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas, tabla-dinámica, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda, tengo una formulario detalle de productos para compras, en la cual se me complica como validar que al agregar un producto a un fila de una tabla no se duplique el producto he intentado de alguna forma pero no logro controlar que no se dupliquen los productos, que al ingresar un producto  salga un mensaje "el  producto ya esta agregado a la compra". los campos input al agregar el producto son generado y al agregar se suma subtotal. y total

-los datos del producto los trae desde una Db.c

- tabla detalle de producto, los productos agregados se muestran en tbody

  ```
    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">

                            <div class="table-responsive active-projects">
                              <table class="table  table-hover table-sm" id="add_compras">
                                <thead class="table-light">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Acción</th>
                                    <th>Productos</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>P.Compra</th>
                                    <th>P.Venta</th>
                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="detalle">

                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div>

                          </div>

                        </div>
  ```

espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias.

en la tabla productos capturo el id del mismo y lo agrego al detalle de compra como se muestra en la imagen, quisiera controlar que al agregar el producto no se duplique- imagen 1

[image: en la tabla productos capturo el id del mismo y lo agrego al detalle de compra como se muestra en la imagen, quisiera controlar que al agregar el producto no se duplique]

- código JavaScript para capturar los productos imagen 2

```js
/*==============================================================*/
// capturar Productos obtener datos
/*==============================================================*/
var cont=0;
var iba;
total=0;
iva=0;
total_pagar=0;
//un arreglo
subtotal=[];
//funcion para redondeara a 2 decimales
function roundToTwo(num) {    
    return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}
//solo numeros enteros
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
    }
    
function add_productos(id){
    fetch(`?controller=compras&accion=get_datos_productos_idx&id=${id}`)
    .then ((response) => response.json())
    .then ((dataEdita) => {
        console.log(dataEdita);// captura los datos del producto seleccionado
        //almacenamos la data del producto
    //let id_a=dataEdita[0].idproducto;
    //let   producto=dataEdita[0].nombre;
    let cantidad=0;
    let p_compra=0;
    let p_venta=0;
    idc=dataEdita[0].idproducto;

var fila= ` <tr class="selected" id="fila${[cont]}">
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');" ><i class="fas fas fa-times"></i></button></td>
    <td id="${id}">
    <input  class="form-control artixy"  type="text" name="idarticulo[]" value="${dataEdita[0].idproducto}">${dataEdita[0].nombre}</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" style="width: 80%;height:30%" type="number"  name="cantidad[]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input style="width:80%;height:30%" class="form-control" type="number" name="p_compra[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input style="width:80%;height:30%" class="form-control" type="number" name="p_venta[]" value=""></td>
    <td>${subtotal[cont]}</td>
    </tr>`;
    cont++;
    $('#detalle').append(fila); 
    })

}
```

[image: este es mi código JavaScript para capturar los productos]

[image: he intentado controlar por el id del que se genera del id del producto agregado]

Comment: Pon todo el código necesario _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Cuando creas la fila puedes tambien agregar el Id del producto a un array de Javascript, y cada vez que eligen un nuevo producto, recorres el array buscando si ya existe el Id. Si existe, sumas 1 a la cantidad o le dices que  ya existe. Ademas si solo agregars una fila HTML ¿como vas a actualizar despues la tabla de productos vendidos?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, al agregar un producto tengo un contador que se incrementa y agrega una nueva fila a la tabla con el producto seleccionado.